# How to make "export default" work in a Babel plugin file?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I took this plugin example straight from the docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#plugin-development)

```
export default function() {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Identifier(path) {
        const name = path.node.name;
        // reverse the name: JavaScript -> tpircSavaJ
        path.node.name = name.split("").reverse().join("");
      }
    }
  };
}
```

My `babel.config.js` file is this:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs',
        './babelPlugin.js',
    ],
    presets: [
        '@babel/env'
    ]
} ;
```

I run Babel with the command `babel testInput.js -o testOutput.js`

But I get this error:

```
D:\Projects\Babel plugin test\babelPlugin.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {   export default function() {
                                                                ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

If instead of `export default` I use `module.exports =`, everything works fine.

Why is `export default` causing a syntax error?

Comment: Problem is your babel's config because this syntax works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel will compile `testInput.js` because that's what `babel testInput.js -o testOutput.js` says, but nothing in your config will compile `babelPlugin.js`. If you want to write it with ES6 module syntax, you'd need to separately compile the plugin first.